# The exit status of the process is printed before it exits

Tags: c, shell, exit

```
void execute(char **argv,int num)
{
    int i;
    pid_t  pid;
    int    status;
    int child_status;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) 
    {     /* fork a child process*/
        printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) 
    {          /* for the child process: */
        int c;
        if (c==execvp(argv[0], argv) < 0) 
        {     /* execute the command  */
            printf("%d\n", c);
            printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");
            perror(" ");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else if(bg!=1){
        while (waitpid(pid,&status,WNOHANG|WUNTRACED));
    }
    else if(bg==1)
    {
        wait (&child_status);
        if (WIFEXITED (child_status))
        {
            printf("the child process exited normally, with exit code %d\n",
                    WEXITSTATUS (child_status));
        }
        else
            printf ("the child process exited abnormally\n");
    }
}
```

this is my execute function in my custom shell. When I do something like `gedit &` the exit status is printed before the next prompt is printed. How do I fix this?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "printed before"? Do you want it to print after?

Comment: When the child process exits, it should show the exit status right? Like gedit & opens a text editor in the background. When I click close on that process, then and only then should it show the exit status. Before that the process is still running..right?

Comment: Well, if there is an already running instance of gedit and you run it again, the new instance will exit immediately. Many GUI programs do this, so try with a non GUI one.

Comment: So, this is the `bg==1` case, and `bg` is a global that is set if the command is in the background?

Comment: Yes it is. @jxh

Comment: @redneb Shouldn't it work for GUI programs also? Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Read again the thing that I wrote about gedit. This will not work for gedit. It will work for simpler things such as gnome-calculator.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Regarding the `bg!=1` case. If the child *has not* finished, `waitpid` will return immediately with a value of 0 (because `WNOHANG` is specified), and the `while` loop will end. If the child *has* finished, `waitpid` will return a non-zero number, the `while` loop will call `waitpid` again, `waitpid` will return 0, and the `while` loop will end. So the `bg!=1` case is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what the variable bg is set to, execute() blocks waiting for the function to finish.  In other words, you get the same behavior whether you want to run a process in the background or not.

A few suggestions:

- When you want to run a process in the background, don't call waitpid() or wait() in execute() but instead just return the PID.  The caller would be responsible for detecting when the process terminates.
- If execute() runs a foreground process, return a known non-process PID like -1 so the caller knows not to add it to its list of background processes.
- The caller should probably check its list of background processes before the prompt is printed - after a foreground process completes or a background process has run.  Make sure this is done with non-blocking calls.
- Pass in bg as a parameter to execute